# AWS Cloudformation - How to use If Else conditions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am new to writing AWS Cloudformation templates. I am trying to use If Else conditions on my CF template. How can I use if else statements with resources?

```
If AWS::Region == eu-central-1 ==> create resource , else continue.
```

Answer (score 17):

Define a condition in the conditions sections

```
Conditions:
  createResource: !Equals [ !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'eu-central-1']
```

Then on your resources

```
Resources:
  MyResourcesOnlyCreatedSometime:
    Condition: createResource
    Type: AWS::Blah::Blah
```

Comment: Note to readers: you might reasonably interpret !Equals to mean "not equals" but it does not mean that. It's the YAML/CloudFormation way of saying "call the intrinsic function named Equals". If you wanted "not equals" you would have to chain both !Not and !Equals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works, only the AWS::Region must be a string ( 'AWS::Region' )

Comment: Ah yes, that gets me every time. Edited.